how to fix import matplotlib.pylot as plt can't be recognized I've checked everything and verified that it is installed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
It says that it fails to import the matplotlib.pyplot as plt.
I've checked the Matplotlib uninstalled and installed it. It still shows after doing this. I dunno what to do and keep encountering this problem badly need help on this one.

Could you include some code as well? Will make it easier to find your problem.

Check for Conflicts with Other Packages: Sometimes other installed packages might conflict with Matplotlib.
python -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate  # On Windows, use `myenv\Scripts\activate`
pip install matplotlib


Hi! thank you! is this for making a new environment and installing only matplotlib?

Hi. Yes, the steps are for creating a new Python virtual environment and installing only Matplotlib in that environment.

Hi thank you! I've tried this too but it still wont recognize the maplotlib library
